# How to collect a stream into a CopyOnWriteArrayList

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm getting "Incompatible types, required: CopyOnWriteArrayList, found: Object" with the following. I'm using IntelliJ 2016.1.1.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Foo> l = fields.stream()
                                    .distinct()
                                    .collect(toCollection(CopyOnWriteArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Just guess: maybe you need a typehint somewhere, like `Collections.<Foo>toCollection()` or something like that. And now idea why that was downvoted. Did my part to fix it.

Comment: Wont help. Here are some more characters.

Comment: can you plz put what is your fields variable?

Comment: This compiles fine with javac 1.8.0_52. Try to upgrade Intellij.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `fields` has an inappropriate type, most likely, it has a *raw type*, which will turn the generic invocations of the Stream chain into unchecked operations returning their erased type, which is `Object` for the terminal `collect` call.

Using the right type, this works without problems, i.e.

```
List<String> fields=Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz", "foo");
CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> l =
    fields.stream()
          .distinct()
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(CopyOnWriteArrayList::new));
```

works. But note that building a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` this way is rather expensive as the name “copy on write” already suggests. Copying the entire contents on each insertion leads to quadratic time complexity.

The solution is to collect into a temporary collection, better suited to incremental building, before converting to the desired target type. That copying step might look like overhead, but it’s *linear* overhead, compared to the *quadratic* complexity of collecting directly into the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> l =
    fields.stream()
          .distinct()
          .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                              Collectors.toList(), CopyOnWriteArrayList::new));
```

Note that in this specific case, `distinct` implicitly builds a `Set` behind the scenes, so we can improve the performance by building the `Set` explicitly in place of the temporary `List` and remove the `distinct` step:

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> l =
    fields.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                              Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new),
                              CopyOnWriteArrayList::new));
```

which leads to the conclusion that for this specific use case, we can have it all simpler and potentially even more efficient:

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> l = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(fields));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seams like your fields object is not of type Foo , otherwise it should work find below working code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Foo {


    private String name;

    Foo(String name){

        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo [name=" + name + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fields.add(new Foo("aa"));
        fields.add(new Foo("bb"));
        CopyOnWriteArrayList<Foo> l = fields.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(CopyOnWriteArrayList::new));

        System.out.println("l"+l);
    }


}
```

PS:If your fields is non generic then also this will give error